# How to convert to_char ('DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') and to_date ('DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') using oracle or Plsql

Tags: oracle

select to_date((q.confirm_DATE || ' ' || q.confirm_time),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
from qc_warning_record q
where q.warning_id = 125 ;
ineed show time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHtBV.png)

Comment: I don't understand your question. I see your title, and I see a query where you reference q.date and q.varchar2. Are you asking us to guess what those are? Or what?

Comment: sorry  it new code select to_date((q.confirm_DATE || ' ' || q.confirm_time),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi')
from qc_warning_record q
where q.warning_id = 125

Comment: I still don't understand. What is q.confirm_DATE? I mean: what is its data type, and what are some illustrative values it may have? And the same for q.confirm_time.

Comment: confirm_DATE  data type is date;
confirm_time data type is varchar2;

Comment: Do you understand my questions? 1. What are the DATA TYPES? Is the first one a DATE, and if so, what are some typical values? Are they always AT MIDNIGHT? And is the second column of type VARCHAR2, with typical values 22:30 (as in, 10:30 PM)? And, do you need to fuse them together to get a date-time?

Comment: yes i need datetime

Comment: 1. 20-OCT-20
2. 14:30

Comment: Why aren’t you just storing the time component inside the date column? You’re wasting space and making life hard for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the info you provided it seems you are doing something similar.

Please find below a use case.

```
  Create table qc_warning_record(id number,confirm_DATE DATE,confirm_time varchar2(10));
-----------------------------------
INSERT INTO qc_warning_record values(125,sysdate-3, '100012');
  -------------------------------  
 select (to_char(q.confirm_DATE,'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' '|| to_char(to_date(q.confirm_time, 'hh24miss'),'hh24:mi:ss')) DATE_TIME
     from qc_warning_record q where q.id = 125 ;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `q.confirm_date` is a date and `q.confirm_time` is a string (in format HH24:MI), and you need to create a value of date (date-time) data type, combining the date (truncated to midnight) from the first column with the time from the second, you could do this:

```
to_date( to_char(q.confirm_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') || ' ' || q.confirm_time
       , 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'
       )
```

You won't be able to see time-of-day if you query dates and your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to dd-MON-rr. To change it, you must first run

```
alter session set nls_date_format='dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi';
```